# Java split() not working as expected

Tags: java

I currently have text where I have "TweetJSONObject\r\n09/19/14TweetJSONObject" where the TweetJSONObject is just a tweet in json format. Now I'm using the .split() function to try separate the tweets from one another but it would seem that \r\n09/19/14 isn't an appropriate split string? Here is the code:

```
String[] value = line.split("\r\n09/19/14");

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("hello.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println(value[0]);
writer.close();
```

The text file 'hello', when I open it is just the following string again, "TweetJSONObject\r\n09/19/14TweetJSONObject". Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be \\r\\n09/19/14 ? \ is just an escape char \r means tab and \n means newline.

Comment: `System.out.println (Arrays.toString("TweetJSONObject\r\n09/19/14TweetJSONObject".split ("\r\n09/19/14")));` prints `[TweetJSONObject, TweetJSONObject]`, so I'm not sure what's the problem.

Comment: @wrongAnswer `\r` is actually `Carriage Return`(CR for short) and not Tab (`\t`)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
String[] value = line.split("\\\\r\\\\n09/19/14");
```

---

### Why so many backslashes?

In literal Java strings the backslash is an escape character. The literal string `"\\"` is a single backslash. In regular expressions, the backslash is also an escape character. The regular expression `\\` matches a single backslash. So this regular expression as a Java string, becomes `"\\\\"`.

Comment: @user12345 Your `hello.txt` contains literal backslashes, `\ `. This is a RegEx control char, so it needs to be escaped in RegEx: `\\ ` and it is a Java String escape char, so these `\\ ` need to be escaped as well, resulting in `"\\\\"` for a plaintext `\ ` matching regex. (BTW: This markup seems to treat \ special as well :( )

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the library method `Pattern.quote` instead of trying to escape stuff on your own (which is too confusing and error prone). A small runnable example:

```
package net.sanjayts;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "TweetJSONObject\r\n09/19/14TweetJSONObject";
        String[] parts = s.split(Pattern.quote("\r\n09/19/14"));
        System.out.println(parts[0] + " --- " + parts[1]);
    }
}

//Output: TweetJSONObject --- TweetJSONObject
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slashes

```
String[] value = line.split("\\\\r\\\\n09/19/14");

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("hello.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println(value[0]);
writer.close();
```